# Question about meaning of "painted-on hair and dress"

Tags: word-meaning

> When I was a child, I had a family of doll people. They lived in a red shoebox painted to look like a house, with a dark-brown roof and yellow awnings. Inside the house, there was a set of plastic toy furniture, plus some random household items: a matchbox television, a mirror crafted from a piece of foil, and a thick rug secretly cut out of my old sweater. I also had a few plastic farm animals—a cow, a pig, a goat, and a very large (larger than the cow) chicken, which lived outside the shoebox.
>
> The family itself consisted of the following individuals:
>
> One pretty little doll, made of soft plastic, **with painted-on hair and dress** , who, in my games, represented me.
>
> One naked, bald, vaguely female doll, made of hard shiny plastic, whom I designated the mother. I made her a Greek-style tunic out of an old handkerchief and glued a lock of my own hair to her head.

With this assumption in mind that **painted-on dress** means **thight dress**, according to this link:

http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/painted-on

What does it means when saying **with painted-on hair and dress** ?

1. with colored hair and colored dress ( colored with ink or sonething )
2. with colored hair and thight dress

it is difficult for a little girl to color a piece of clothing.

Answer (score 2):

Your dictionary link is not relevant here. The hair and dress were literally painted on the doll. The child had painted hair and a dress onto the plastic doll.

[Here](http://media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/0e/ca/90/0eca905ca1ca0fbcb762c5ebc1b20333.jpg) is a doll with painted-on hair.